# Number of n-tuples in $\{0, 1, 2\}$ with sum less than or equal to $d$.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

I would like to know if there is an expression for the number of n-tuples of $\mathbb{Z}$, where each component is an integer between $0$ and $2$, and the sum of the components is less than or equal to some number $d \in [0,2n]$.

I am also interested if this expression could be generalised for integer n-tuples with components between $0$ and $q$, with the sum of the components being less than or equal to some given number $d \in [0, (q-1)n]$, but would appreciate an answer for just the case $q=3$.

I know from (a slight alteration of) [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212649/the-number-of-n-tuples-with-a-sum-less-than-m-is-c-mn?rq=1) post that the number of n-tuples of non-negative integers with the sum of components less than or equal to $d$ is equal to $d+n \choose n$. But I'm not sure if this information helps.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. It is hard to find a reading of the original question with your later-stated equivalent, even if you only include monomials instead of polynomials. The sum of elements in $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ are elements of $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z.$ You can get each of the sums $\mathbb /q\mathbb Z$ equally likely. And we don't usually order $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z.$

Comment: I'll try to reword what I'm asking. I want to know an expression for the number of $n$-tuples of non-negative integers, where each component is less than $q$, and the sum of each component is less than or equal to some integer $d$.

Comment: The degrees of those polynomials are ordinary integers (natural numbers even). It is extremely confusing for you to refer to them as elements of $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$. You do know that in $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ we have $0=q$, $-1=q-1$ et cetera.  Also, if I'm allowed to nitpick: the polynomials $x^q$ and $x$ are different. They just have the same value at all the points of $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$. But, there I understand quite well what you mean. You want to calculate the dimension of the space of polynomial function of total degree $\le d$.

Comment: About your actual question. In the case $q=2$ this would be easy, the sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=0}^d\binom n k$, and known from the theory of binary Reed-Muller codes. Not sure how well that generalizes to $q=3$ and above. Looks like we need a generating function like $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{q-1})^n$. Too late for me to think straight :-(

Comment: As you've stated it in comments, this has nothing to do with . $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z,$ but really about sums of $n$ integers, each from $0$ to $q-1.$

Comment: Also, the value you assert is $\binom{d+1}{n}$ is actually $\binom{d+n}{n}.$

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I agree that I've written the problem in a confusing way. Rather than restricting the problem to $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$, I should have just bounded each integer component between $0$ and $q−1$. I'll edit my post to pose the question in a less confusing manner.

Comment: Also Jyrki, if I may ask, what exactly does it mean for two functions to be the same, if not taking the same value at every point of their domain?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - You mentioned the $q=2$ case is equivalent to cumulative sums of binomial coefficients, which are known from Reed Muller codes.  I was not aware that those cumulative sums are well studied or have a closed form solution.  Can you point me to some reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer can be found with the principle of inclusion exclusion, by taking all $\binom{n+d}{n}$ vectors, then subtracting for each coordinate the $\binom{n+d-q}{n}$ vectors where the coordinate is too large, then adding back in the doubly subtracted vectors, etc. The result is
$$
\bbox[5px, #fbfbfb, border: solid black 2px]{\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+d-qk}{n}.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For the case of $\{0,1,2\}$, an alternate view is to let $a,b,c$ be the number of $0, 1,2$ respectively.  Then we have $b + 2c \le d$ and so the answer is:

$$\sum_{b,c}  {n! \over (n-b-c)! b! c!}$$

where the summation is over all $(b,c)$ s.t. $b\ge 0, c\ge 0, b+2c \le d$.  For this $q=3$ case this can be easily done with a double (nested) summation, one on each variable.

I think this is less efficient to calculate than the I-E based answer by @MikeEarnest but at least this is an alternate method.  I wouldn't try this for large $q$ though as the number of summations is $q-1$.